# SIM binding via text messages to verify the user's mobile number in iOS App Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-telephony

I'm developing an iOS  app and need a secure method to detect SIM changes. Given the deprecation of serviceSubscriberCellularProviders and restrictions on accessing SIM details like IMSI or ICCID, traditional methods aren't viable. I've observed apps like Google Pay and PhonePe implement SIM binding via text messages to verify the user's mobile number.

How can we detect SIM changes in iOS, ensuring compliance with App Store privacy policies? I'm looking for alternative approaches that enhance security without directly accessing restricted SIM information. I have used CTTelephonyNetworkInfo() and it’s subscriberCellularProvider but those data are deprecated from iOS 16.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no functionality on iOS to access carrier or sim data. The classes you mentioned are *deprecated without replacement*.  It doesn't matter what functionality is available on android. It isn't available on iOS. Why do you care about sim changes? A phone number is not a reliable authentication factor

Comment: Asking the same question that has [already been closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77939130/how-to-implement-sim-binding-in-an-ios-app-for-enhanced-security#comment137404345_77939130) using a different account is also not appreciated.